# Arduino ds3231to TM1638 problems,alarm clock project

Tags: power, led

Good morning,
I am coding an alarm clock on arduino by using a DS3231 and a TM1638.
The code works and the time updates in the serial monitor,although the time doesn't update on the tm1638.
I'll attach the code here:

```
#include <DS3231.h>  
#include <TM1638.h> 
#include <Streaming.h>  
#include <SPI.h>  
#include <Wire.h>  
#include <InvertedTM1638.h>  
#include <TM1638.h>  
#include <TM1638QYF.h>  
#include <TM1640.h>  
#include <TM16XX.h>  
#include <TM16XXFonts.h>  
byte buttons;  
#define TM1638_STB D5  
#define TM1638_CLK D6  
#define TM1638_DIO D7  

TM1638 module(TM1638_DIO, TM1638_CLK, TM1638_STB);  
// DS3231 uses I2C - device ID 0x68  
// on Wemos mini pins SDA -> D1 and SCL -> D2  
DS3231 rtc;  
int hours;  
int minutes;  
int seconds;  
bool h12; 
bool PM;  
int data; 
RifTime t;  
char buffer[24];  

void setup()  
{  
  // set up the 7-segment display 
  module.clearDisplay();  
  module.setupDisplay(true, 2);  
  Wire.begin();  
  Serial.begin(115200);  

  Serial.println(F("\nDS3231 Hi Precision Real Time Clock"));  

  // Fill these variables with the date and time.  
  int seconds, minutes, hours, dayofweek, dayofmonth, month, year;  

  // Example for april 15, 2013, 10:08, monday is 2nd day of Week.  
  // Set your own time and date in these variables.  
  // dayofweek = 4; // Day of week, any day can be first, counts 1...7  
  hours = 14; 
  minutes = 30;  
  seconds = 0;  
  year = 2019;  
  month = 8; // month 1...12  
  dayofmonth = 28; // Day of month, 1...31  

  data=( hours * 10000 + minutes * 100 + seconds * 1 ); 

  rtc.setClock(year,month,dayofmonth,hours,minutes,seconds);  
} 

void loop()  
{  
  rtc.getTime(t);  
  Serial << rtc.toString(buffer) << endl;

  delay(1000); // do nothing  

  module.setDisplayToDecNumber(data,4,false);  

  if(seconds==60) 
  { 
    seconds=00; 
    minutes++; 
  } 
  if(minutes==60)
  {
    minutes=0;
    hours++;
  }

  if(hours==24) 
  { 
    data=00000000; 
  } 

  if((data)==143000) 
  { 
    module.setLEDs(0x0001); 
  } 
  else
  {
    module.setLEDs(0x0000);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You set the variable `data` only in the setup function.

You also do not print out `data` to `Serial` but the output of `rtc.toString(buffer)`.

If data is not updated in the `loop` method, the display constantly shows the time you initially set in the setup method.